# Parse & Swift- No results matched the query

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I seem to have a different problem than the previous askers.

I am trying to retrieve my object from Parse in Swift, I use this code

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("mlwVJLH7pa") {
  (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
    println(gameScore)
  } else {
    println(error)
  }
}
```

Ignore the fact that I left GameScore the same...

Anyway's here is an image of my Parse data, to proof the objectId exists.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeFHH.jpg

This is the error I get in the console when running the simulator.

```
2015-07-21 11:10:39.496 ParseStarterProject[959:19643] [Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.5)
Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "No results matched the query." UserInfo=0x7fdeaadb1200 {error=No results matched the query., NSLocalizedDescription=No results matched the query., code=101})
```

Why am I getting an error "No results matched the query" when the objectId does indeed exist?

Comment: Could it possibly be that you didn't change the name of the Class you were querying against? In your picture it looks like the class name is "Content"

Comment: Oh darn, I thought that was a variable for some reason... I'm very inexperienced with Swift as you can probably tell.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed. I apologize for my ignorance. Lol

Comment: Well it's a property on `PFQuery` and a very important one at that. Glad I could help, and don't apologize, we've all been there before! I'll set that as the asnwer and if you could accept it that would be great :)

Comment: A helpful hint: Check out Bolts to go along with Parse. It allows you to chain queries together which you might get to eventually. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that the "className" property on PFQuery matches a class name that you have stored in Parse. In your case, it seems that it should be `var query = PFQuery(className: "Content")` based on the picture that you uploaded.